# Is there anyway to post more than 10 times and call the get to get list of response in rest assured?

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

I have created rest service that post the data into database And GET endpoint to get the data from data base. I want to test this service by posting data multiple times and get the data as list. How can I do this?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with the cucumber framework. You probably need a helper class to track the requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Each GET/POST call has a corresponding returned value, in this case data.  It's a synchronous call, request in/response one.

If you have n GET/POST calls, there's not a way to have a single return with the n responses aggregated.

To aggregate the data in a single response, the individual call has to have all the info necessary to retrieve the data together.

You might want to dig deeper into web services to better understand the concepts, make sure you understand what is the request (which can be GET or POST) and what is a response, if that doesn't fit your use case then you need a different protocol/approach.